# How to count patterns columnwise in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, frequency

I have a matrix S in Matlab that looks like the following:

```
2   2   1   2
2   3   1   1
3   3   1   1
3   4   1   1
3   1   2   1
4   1   3   1
1   1   3   1
```

I would like to count patterns of values column-wise. I am interested into the frequency of the numbers that follow *right after* number 3 in any of the columns. For instance, number 3 occurs three times in the first column. The first time we observe it, it is followed by 3, the second time it is followed by 3 again and the third time it is followed by 4. Thus, the frequency for the patters observed in the first column would look like:

```
3-3: 66.66%
3-4: 33.33% 
3-1: 0%
3-2: 0%
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem statement.  Can you please show us how you calculated those values?

Comment: The percentages provided above are hypothetical and do *not* correspond to the exact percentages one would find in the specific matrix S. The idea is to find how many times does 1/2/3/4 follow number 3 in the columns of the matrix.

Comment: Ok, I still don't understand.  You need to break it down for me.  Imagine that I am a 5 year old child.  Let's look at the first column.  Do you want to count how many times the value of either 1, 2, 3, or 4 follow the number 3?  As I said, an example calculation would be beneficial in understanding your point.  Also, what do those percentages even mean?

Comment: Thank you for your question. In the first column, number 3 occurs three times. The first time we observe it, it is followed by 3, the second time it is followed by 3 again and the third time it is followed by 4. Thus, the frequency for the patters observed in the first column would look like 3-3: 66.66% and 3-4: 33.33% while the combinations 3-1:0% and 3-2:0% are not observed.

Comment: How come the `1` is not observed?  It's the last number in the first column.

Comment: It is not observed *directly* after 3. I am interested in finding the frequency of patters for values that are *right after* 3 (considering just the following row and ignoring the rest of the rows).

Comment: OK, so for a column, once we find a 3, we check the number that follows this and we tally this up?  For example, in the second column, We see the first three, then look at the next entry, which is a 3.  This 3, we see a 4, and so 3-3: 50% and 3-4: 50%?  Do you want a combined percentage over all of the columns?  FWIW, I shouldn't have to keep asking you questions.  This should be in your problem statement.

Comment: One more question to ensure I understand your problem.  Would column 3 be: 3-1: 0%, 3-2: 0%, 3-3: 100%, 3-4: 0%? Would column 4 be all 0%? Also, do you want to collect all of the percentages for all of the columns together and calculate a combined percentage?

Comment: To the SO community: I seemed rather confused and hostile if you examine the myriad of questions at the beginning of this thread.  This was because the original problem lacked sufficient information in order to solve the problem which ultimately got included in the final edited version of the problem. No offence of any kind was intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate the output, you could use the convenient [tabulate](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html)

```
S = [
    2   2   1   2
    2   3   1   1
    3   3   1   1
    3   4   1   1
    3   1   2   1
    4   1   3   1
    1   1   3   1];

idx = find(S(1:end-1,:)==3);
S2 = S(2:end,:);

tabulate(S2(idx))
  Value    Count   Percent
      1        0      0.00%
      2        0      0.00%
      3        4     66.67%
      4        2     33.33%
```

Comment: I find this solution very clean and efficient. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach, finding the 3's then looking at the following digits

```
[i,j]=find(S==3);
k=i+1<=size(S,1);
T=S(sub2ind(size(S),i(k)+1,j(k))) %// the elements of S that are just below a 3
R=arrayfun(@(x) sum(T==x)./sum(k),1:max(S(:))).' %// get the number of probability of each digit
```

Comment: Plus 1 from me as well.  This was my initial approach, but I decided to use `accumarray` as I found it to be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to restate your problem statement in a way that I can understand and my solution will reflect this new problem statement.

1. For a particular column, locate the locations that contain the number 3.
2. Look at the row immediately below these locations and look at the values at these locations
3. Take these values and tally up the total number of occurrences found.
4. Repeat these for all of the columns and update the tally, then determine the percentage of occurrences for the values.

We can do this by the following:

```
A = [2   2   1   2
2   3   1   1
3   3   1   1
3   4   1   1
3   1   2   1
4   1   3   1
1   1   3   1]; %// Define your matrix
[row,col] = find(A(1:end-1,:) == 3);
vals = A(sub2ind(size(A), row+1, col));
h = 100*accumarray(vals, 1) / numel(vals)

h =

          0
          0
    66.6667
    33.3333
```

Let's go through the above code slowly.  The first few lines define your example matrix `A`.  Next, we take a look at all of the rows **except for the last row** of your matrix and see where the number 3 is located with [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html).  We skip the last row because we want to be sure we are within the bounds of your matrix.  If there is a number 3 located at the last row, we would have undefined behaviour if we tried to check the values below the last because there's nothing there!

Once we do this, we take a look at those values in the matrix that are 1 row beneath those that have the number 3.  We use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to help us facilitate this.  Next, we use these values and tally them up using [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) then normalize them by the total sum of the tallying into percentages.

The result would be a 4 element array that displays the percentages encountered per number.

To double check, if we look at the matrix, we see that the value of 3 follows other values of 3 for a total of 4 times - first column, row 3, row 4, second column, row 2 and third column, row 6.  The value of 4 follows the value of 3 two times: first column, row 6, second column, row 3.

In total, we have 6 numbers we counted, and so dividing by 6 gives us 4/6 or 66.67% for number 3 and 2/6 or 33.33% for number 4.

Comment: Nice use of `accumarray`, and you got around the final row issue cleanly as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I got the problem statement correctly, you could efficiently implement this with [**`MATLAB's logical indexing`**](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html#btjk576-1) and an approach that is essentially of two lines -

```
%// Input 2D matrix
S = [
    2   2   1   2
    2   3   1   1
    3   3   1   1
    3   4   1   1
    3   1   2   1
    4   1   3   1
    1   1   3   1]

Labels = [1:4]'; %//'# Label array

counts = histc(S([false(1,size(S,2)) ; S(1:end-1,:) == 3]),Labels)
Percentages = 100*counts./sum(counts)
```

---

### Verify/Present results

The styles for presenting the output results listed next use [**`MATLAB's table`**](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) for a well *human-readable* format of data.

**Style #1**

```
>> table(Labels,Percentages)
ans = 
    Labels    Percentages
    ______    ___________
    1              0     
    2              0     
    3         66.667     
    4         33.333
```

**Style #2**

You can do some fancy string operations to present the results in a more "representative" manner -

```
>> Labels_3 = strcat('3-',cellstr(num2str(Labels','%1d')'));
>> table(Labels_3,Percentages)
ans = 
    Labels_3    Percentages
    ________    ___________
    '3-1'            0     
    '3-2'            0     
    '3-3'       66.667     
    '3-4'       33.333
```

**Style #3**

If you want to present them in descending sorted manner based on the percentages as listed in the expected output section of the question, you can do so with an additional step using `sort` -

```
>> [Percentages,idx] = sort(Percentages,'descend');
>> Labels_3 = strcat('3-',cellstr(num2str(Labels(idx)','%1d')'));
>> table(Labels_3,Percentages)
ans = 
    Labels_3    Percentages
    ________    ___________
    '3-3'       66.667     
    '3-4'       33.333     
    '3-1'            0     
    '3-2'            0
```

---

### Bonus Stuff: Finding frequency (counts) for all cases

Now, let's suppose you would like repeat this process for say `1`, `2` and `4` as well, i.e. find occurrences after `1`, `2` and `4` respectively. In that case, you can iterate the above steps for all cases and for the same you can use `arrayfun` -

```
%// Get counts
C = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n) histc(S([false(1,size(S,2)) ; S(1:end-1,:) == n]),...
    1:4),1:4,'Uni',0))

%// Get percentages
Percentages = 100*bsxfun(@rdivide, C, sum(C,1))
```

Giving us -

```
Percentages =
   90.9091   20.0000         0  100.0000
    9.0909   20.0000         0         0
         0   60.0000   66.6667         0
         0         0   33.3333         0
```

Thus, in `Percentages`, the first column are the counts of `[1,2,3,4]` that occur right after there is a `1` somewhere in the input matrix. As as an example, one can see `column -3` of `Percentages` is what you had in the sample output when looking for elements right after `3` in the input matrix.

Comment: Nice solution. I think that table function is only available to Matlab 2014! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute frequencies **independently for each column**:

```
S = [2   2   1   2
     2   3   1   1
     3   3   1   1
     3   4   1   1
     3   1   2   1
     4   1   3   1
     1   1   3   1];                                    %// data: matrix
N = 3;                                                  %// data: number
r = max(S(:));
[R, C] = size(S);
[ii, jj] = find(S(1:end-1,:)==N);                       %// step 1
count = full(sparse(S(ii+1+(jj-1)*R), jj, 1, r, C));    %// step 2
result = bsxfun(@rdivide, count, sum(S(1:end-1,:)==N)); %// step 3
```

This works as follows:

1. [`find`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) is first applied to determine row and col indices of occurrences of `N` in `S` except its last row.
2. The values in the entries *right below* the indices of step 1 are accumulated for each column, in variable `count`. The very convenient [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function is used for this purpose. Note that this uses [linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/02/08/linear-indexing/) into `S`.
3. To obtain the frequencies for each column, `count` is divided (with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)) by the number of occurrences of `N` in each column.

The result in this example is

```
result =
         0         0         0       NaN
         0         0         0       NaN
    0.6667    0.5000    1.0000       NaN
    0.3333    0.5000         0       NaN
```

Note that the last column correctly contains `NaN`s because the frequency of the sought patterns is undefined for that column.